# Writing from Frame to Frame in a Complex Frame Structure (3 Cols each with 3 Rows) on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, frames

I used the following code to write from one frame to another in Mozilla and IE and it worked perfectly:

```
top.framename.document.write("blablabla")
```

It however didn't work on Google Chrome.

Can someone please tell me what code works on Chrome for this task?

Answer (score 0):

I've deployed the site to a server, and strangely it now works perfectly well on Chrome! So this problem seems to have resolved itself - or perhaps Chrome heard and responded swiftly. Either way, I'm elated!